# how to make yolov7 training with 1 class from cocodataset

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I am working on yolov7, train.py files.
I want to use cocodataset, but take 1 class for training: person. Coco have 80 class.
Can i control this from train.py?
Train py has ;

```
parser.add_argument('--single-cls', action='store_true', help='train multi-class data as single-class')
```

option. But i have no idea how can i use this command.

Also, train log says;

```
tensorboard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs/train', view at http://localhost:6006/
```

But page gives nothing.

Comment: try to share some more data like which repo are you using etc. so that it would be easy to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use all 80 classes you have to use detect.py. With train.py you can train your custom dataset to detect your custom object.
Tensorboard. First, you have to install with

```
$ pip install tensorboard
```

if you have trained with train.py, you can run tensorboard with this command:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir=runs/train
```

And you can see results in http://localhost:6006/